# Ubuntu touch on note 10.1 (2014) WITHOUT rooting

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-touch, android, samsung, tablet

I just purchased a Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 2014 edition (SM-P600) and wanted to test Ubuntu on it (and maybe on my Galaxy S4 as well). It is still under warranty, so I do not want to root it or do anything to void the warranty. Any ideas on how to do this? I was thinking there may be a way using a virtual machine in Android?

Answer (score 0):

Im sorry, by putting any other os on the phone you are voiding the warranty here is rogers guideline explaining why it voids your warranty:

> 3. Why does “rooting” an Android device void its warranty? Rooting is when you wipe your handset clean of its existing operating system
>      and install a new version. The problem with rooting is that handset
>      manufacturers install and customize the OS to work specifically with
>      their device so clearing it may make some features and functionality
>      not work correctly.  Furthermore, all handsets sold by Rogers are
>      verified to work on our network before giving them to customers. In
>      turn, it’s impossible for us to troubleshoot or provide technical
>      assistance on a device that is no longer in line with that
>      verification. That, in a nutshell, is why rooting voids the warranty
>      of Rogers-purchased devices.

In which it states changing the os voids the warrant.

I suggest if you want to keep your warranty to not do this, as there is no legal way of changing the os and not loosing your warranty!

Thanks, hope this helps.

To read more about the warranty issue read [here.](http://redboard.rogers.com/2010/redboard%E2%80%99s-faaq-frequently-asked-android-questions/)

Comment: You did NOT read the question. I want to do it WITHOUT rooting (ie. in a virtual drive in Android), which would not void the warranty as I would not be removing the old OS or modifying it in any way, just installing another app in it.

Comment: FWIW, it is a good idea not to void the warranty. I had to send my p600 in twice for repair.The screen failed twice for no reason. I don't abuse my tablet, so it shouldn't have failed... twice.  I wouldn't recommend Samsung again. And their customer service was horrid.

Comment: Why don't you research it. https://www.google.ca/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=sjrUVMblLO3C-APHkIGgDg&gws_rd=ssl#q=virtual+machine+on+android+tablet

Comment: Exactly, I don't want to risk the warranty. And those links come up with ways of running android in a virtual pc on a windows or linux desktop, or ways of rooting your phone to do it. I do NOT want to root my phone and I want the virtual machine to run in android, not the other way around.

Comment: Rooting is not wiping the existing OS. Rooting is getting root permission and add or remove some functionnality at will. Rogers, whoever this is, is wrong even in the definition of rooting.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a Dualboot configuration works for you. According to this (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/DualBootInstallation) guide you need to unlock your bootloader.

I am not sure, how this affects your warranty. The statement quoted by @TrevorClarke talks only about removing the original OS (which should be kept when using a dual boot).